# mysqli - I am trying to get substring working

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT update_log, update_idccode, update_filenumber, update_filetype, update_timedate 
FROM updates_log
WHERE substring(update_idccode,0,7) ='idc2997%' AND update_filetype = 'E'
ORDER BY update_log DESC
```

I am trying to get this to get the first 7 characters of my update_idccode table column.  I cannot get it to work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no `mysqli` there. `mysqli` is a PHP API to MySQL databases. Your question is just about the query, not about the PHP part.

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling out 7 chars from your column, and comparing them against an 8-char string. In other words, it is imposssible for a 7-char word to ever be identical to an 8-char word.

Try

```
WHERE substring(update_idccode,0,7) = 'idc2997'  ...
```

instead. As an alternative,

```
WHERE update_idccode LIKE 'idc2997%' ...
```

would also work. The `%` suggests you may have been trying this, but `%` is only relevant as a wildcard in `LIKE` comparisons, not `=` equality testing.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` starts at 1 in SQL.

Comment: either way, it's still only pulling out 7 characters

Comment: But you need to change your recommended answer to use `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: It did not work.  Still getting nothing back when it should find 2 records.

Comment: You have answered my question.  Starts with one.  Thank you for all your help.  Much appreciated!